# How to invoke text of a div properly on cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm having troubles with the invoke('text') of this div and I don't know why:

```
<div class="MuiDataGrid-cell MuiDataGrid-cell--textLeft" role="cell" data-field="description" data-colindex="2" aria-colindex="3" tabindex="-1" style="min-width: 234px; max-width: 234px; min-height: 36px; max-height: 36px; line-height: 35px;">TEXT</div>
```

My code is this:

```
cy.get('[data-rowindex="0"]').find('[data-field="description"]').invoke('text').then(text => {
            cy.get('.css-1e8jzdq').eq(1).find('input').type(text)
        })
```

What I want it to take the text of the div and use it to type into a search input but it doesn't work because `cy.type() cannot accept an empty string. You need to actually type something.`

I don't know what I'm missing with this invoke... any help?

Comment: Your above code is correct. `invoke(text)` is not working because cypress is getting an empty string at your given locator.

Comment: What should I invoke then?

Comment: You have to look into your locator. Rest everything remains the same.

Comment: But I think my locator is ok. If I write this assert `cy.get('[data-rowindex="0"]').find('[data-field="description"]').invoke('text').should('contain', 'TEXT')` is correct

Comment: Can you run this and check what is getting printed `cy.get('[data-rowindex="0"]')
  .find('[data-field="description"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text)
  })`

Comment: Nothing. It's an empty string

Comment: Refer to my first comment. You need to change your locator so that your intended text is found

Comment: Well, as you said, I can do it if I hardcode my item id `cy.get('[data-id="1020"] > [data-field="description"]')` It's not my solution but at least I can see the problem. Thank you!